# What doing the new tracking element with attribute value 'usermatch'?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

Just saw new custom element `<custom name="usermatch" type="tracking" />` on one of marketing cloud templates.

And why there are two tracking elements in one template?

[image]

Comment: can you share which template you found this in?

Comment: It was found in basic template called 'Hero 1 Column'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"user match" sounds very much like the new Salesforce DMP integration for emails that came with the October release. See the corresponding page in the release notes. Unless you actually use Salesforce DMP you don't need this additional tracking element.

Release notes, integrations: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/october_2017_release/integrations/